# Elasticsearch: conditional/disabling sorting if too many hits

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

When I perform a search, and want to disable the sorting (hence a faster return time), I use

```
  "sort": [
    "_doc"
  ],
```

Which effectively disables sorting. Is there a way to tell ES to sort this way (or not at all), IF there are more than 100 results for example? I.e. I want ES to sort one way for when hits < 100 and another way for when hits > 100.

Hope this makes sense and possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conditional based sort on result size. Your best bet would be using [count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) from app as first pass query and then sort based on your needs. Tuning index based on sort param would be another effective way.

Comment: How about Script-based sorting? It seems to be roughly doing what I'm after?

Comment: But you need access to whole result set count first - AFAIK that information is not available on sorting script exec time

Comment: Why is that though? I presumed it does the searching first (so it knows the count as well) and then starts scoring/sorting..